# sql subset query

Tags: sql, postgresql

An SQL question about subsets,

Consider a database design of a recipe table, ingredient table and a recipe_ingredient joining table. We will only need the joining table for this problem.

```
recipe_ingredient table:

 Column |  Type   | Modifiers 
--------+---------+-----------
 r_id   | integer | # Key to the recipe table
 i_id   | integer | # Key to the ingredient table
```

A recipe requires 1 or more ingredients.
Given a list of ingredient ids is it possible to find all compatible recipes? A compatible recipe would have a subset of the supplied ingredients.

This query is close. It allows me to see all the ingredient ids required by each recipe.

```
 select array_agg(i_id), r_id from recipe_ingredient group by r_id
```

I could run the above query and then compare the ingredient list with my own list in code. But I would like to know if everything can be done at the SQL level,

What I would like to do is this:

```
select array_agg(i_id), r_id from recipe_ingredient group by r_id 
HAVING array_agg(i_id) IS_SUBSET_OF (:INGREDIENT_LIST)
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a recipes table:

```
select r.*
from recipes r
where not exists (select 1
                  from recipe_ingredient ri
                  where ri.r_id = r.id and
                        ri.i_id not in ( . . . )
                 );
```

This gets all recipes that have no ingredients outside your list.

Comment: Should't it be `ri.i_id NOT in ( . . . )`?

Comment: I think with Adam's suggested change that should work. Thanks.

Comment: How fast is this kind of query?

Comment: With an index on `recipe_ingredient(r_id, i_id)` it should be quite fast.

Answer (score -1):

Put your ingredient list to a temp table variable:

```
DECLARE @selectedIngredientList TABLE (id INT);

SELECT DISTINCT r_id
FROM recipe_ingredient ri INNER JOIN @selectedIngredientList i
  ON ri.i_id = i.id
```

Comment: Nope, This will return the recipes that match one ingredient in the list - it won't return recipes that contain only a subset of the ingredient list.